# Async and await vs ThreadPool / TaskFactory

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

In a fire-and-forget scenario, is there any advantage to decorating your method with async and  awaiting something awaitable, as opposed to just using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem or Task.Factory.StartNew?

Comment: Both are different. awaiting *doesn't* meant fire and forget. It means you're deliberately waiting for it to complete!

Comment: Easy to overlook that a fire-and-forget thread always has a result that should be checked.  An *exception* is a result too.  And very easy to burn a tp thread to make slow method calls that are I/O bound, the point of using a thread but exactly the one thing a tp thread should not do.  Async/await help you avoid these shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, a "fire and forget scenario" hardly ever happens. Consider: what if the operation fails?

---

`async` and `await` are about freeing up the current thread. For UI apps, this gives you responsiveness; for server-side apps, this gives you scalability.

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` (and the new `Task.Run`) are for scheduling work for a thread pool thread. They enable you to schedule CPU-bound (or blocking) work to a background thread.

The purposes of these two approaches *sound* similar, but they are actually quite different. Async/await works best with non-CPU-bound work. For example, downloading a resource from a server is an I/O-bound operation; the `async`/`await` approach does not block a thread for that download. However, if you have CPU-bound work to do, and don't want to tie up the UI thread, then `async` by itself won't help you - you would queue the work to the thread pool via `Task.Run`.